# PHP wrapping numbers with for loop

Tags: php, loops

I have this php code:

```
$count = 8;

    echo '<div style="background-color:green">';

    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        echo $i;

        if($i%2 == 0) {
            echo '</div><div style="background-color:green">';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
```

What this will do is to wrap the numbers in a div with green background color every 2. I wanted to make something like in the snippet

```html
<div style="background-color:green">12</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow">34</div>
<div style="background-color:green">56</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow">78</div>
```

how can i do this in php? please help. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: _how can i do this in php?_ you already did it in php didn't you?

Comment: no i didnt... the snippet is pure html.

Comment: Huh... I meant your php code you have posted

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that effect doing something like this:

```
<?php   
    $count          = 8;
    $colorMatrix    = ['odd'=>'green', 'even'=>'yellow'];

    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        $oddEven    = ($i%2) ? "odd" : "even";
        echo "<div style='background-color:{$colorMatrix[$oddEven]}'>{$i}</div>";   
    }
```

Or even much simpler and straightforward:

```
    $count          = 8;        
    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        $oddEven    = ($i%2) ? "green" : "yellow";
        echo "<div style='background-color:{$oddEven}'>{$i}</div>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To match your snippet, start at 12 and increment 22 on each iteration. changed to DRY for my fans.

```
<?php
$start = 12;
$end = 78;

for ($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i=$i+22) {
    echo '<div style="background-color:'.($i%4 == 0 ? 'green' : 'yellow').'">'.$i.'</div>';
}
```

Result:

```
<div style="background-color:green">12</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow">34</div>
<div style="background-color:green">56</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow">78</div>
```

You could also achieve the same with using a `foreach` with a `range()`:

```
foreach (range(12, 78, 22) as $i => $num) {
    echo '<div style="background-color:'.($i%2 == 0 ? 'green' : 'yellow').'">'.$num.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: @bub    Nice observation.... but Masters can't go wrong so +10 for a Master... it can be inferred he has his good reasons....

Comment: @Poiz ...master? Btw you got my upvoote cause you dont repeat ;) Almost never there is a good reason for repeating...just a matter of code design

Comment: @bub        That was just a poke at humour, Dude... wasn't meant to be taken seriously... The main Point to take home is that ***You made a Nice Observation of Repetition: violation of the DRY Principle***. Everyone is only a Master to and of himself but then we must mix Fun and Humour if we have to  stay sane in an insane world, shouldn't we now.... ?

Comment: @Poiz yes master :) totally right ;) and ty for the praise

Comment: @Laurence Cherone thanks for the effort but all those wont do what i want. I wanted to make the effect of the snippet. all this does is to check if the number is odd or even. thats not what i asked...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using if else condition . suppose if $i is odd then color yellow then other green . i have added some option which give you same result.

**Option 1.**

```
<?php
    $count = 8;
    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        $color = $i%2 == 0 ? 'green' : 'yellow';
        echo '<div style="background-color:'.$color.'">'.$i.'</div>';
    }
```

**Option 2.**

```
<?php
$count = 8;
for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
    if ($i%2 == 0) {
        $color = 'green';
    } else {
        $color = 'yellow';
    }
    echo '<div style="background-color:'.$color.'">'.$i.'</div>';
}
```

**Option 3.**

```
<?php
$count = 8;
for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
    $color = 'yellow';
    if ($i%2 == 0) {
        $color = 'green';
    }
    echo '<div style="background-color:'.$color.'">'.$i.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: For offering more than one route that lead to the same destination, you earned it! +10

Comment: thanks for the effort but all those wont do what i want. I wanted to make the effect of the snippet. all this does is to check if the number is odd or even. thats not what i wnated...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
$count = 8;

        for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {        

            if($i%2 == 0) {
                echo '</div><div style="background-color:green">'.$i;
            }else{
                echo '<div style="background-color:yellow">'.$i;
            }

            echo '</div>'
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but all those wont do what i want. I wanted to make the effect of the snippet. all this does is to check if the number is odd or even. thats not what i wnated...